# Distributing 3 distinct balls in 5 distinct boxes such that a box can be empty

Tags: combinatorics, solution-verification, balls-in-bins

My approach :-

I made the following cases :-

let the balls be A,B,C and Boxes be B1, B2, B3, B4, B5

**Case 1)** 1 1 1 0 0  ---> 3c1 * 2c1 * 1c1 (These 6 cases in my opinion are representing a particular order in which the balls are being filled in the 5 boxes: ABC, ACB, BAC, BCA, CAB, CBA ), for example here BCA which means that B ball is filled first in a particular box , followed by C ball which further is followed by A in end, how shall I permute each of these 6 cases into the boxes?

What I thought here for example in the case of ABC (A being filled first , then B , followed by C in end) , I tried to make the following cases :

```
 B1        B2       B3       B4        B5  

 A         B        C         0         0  -> (the case in which A is first placed in Box 1 followed by B ball in box 2 and C ball in box 3) 

 A         B        0         C         0 -> the case where A is filled first in box 1 followed by B in box 2 and then C in box 4)

 A         B        0         0         C 

 0         A        B         C         0

 0         A        B         0         C

 0         A        0         B         C

 B         A        C         0         0 -> **the case where B is filled first in box 1 followed by A in box 2 and then C in box 3)**
.
.
.
.
```

Am I doing it correctly ?

**Case 2)** 2 1 0 0 0 ---> 3c2 * 1c1 would give me the order in which the balls would be filled like here I would have 3 cases {AB,C},{AC,B}, {BC, A}, how shall I permute each of these 3 cases into the boxes ?

**Case 3)** and finally the case of 3 0 0 0 0 ---> 3c3 would give me 1 case of {A,B,C} , how to permute this 1 case ?

I am struggling to understand after the initial ordering of balls , how shall I permute them further into the boxes ?

Comment: Case 1 has $5 \times 4 \times 3 = 60$ possibilities: put each ball in turn into an empty box.  Case 2 has $5 \times 3 \times 4=60$ possibilities: choose a box and put two balls in it then choose another box and put the remaining ball in.  Case 3 has $5$ possibilities: choose a box and put all the balls into it.  Combined they have $5^3=125$ possibilities: choose a box (empty or not) for each ball

Comment: You have to select which boxes will receive the balls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What matters here is which ball is placed in which box.  You have to select which box will receive which ball.

**Method 1:**  There are five ways to place each ball, so the three distinct balls can be placed in five distinct boxes in $5^3 = 125$ ways.

**Method 2:** We consider cases.

*Case 1*: Each ball is placed in a separate box.

There are five ways to place ball A in one of the boxes, which leaves four ways to place ball B in a different box.  That, in turn, leaves three ways to place ball C in one of the remaining boxes.  Hence, as Henry indicated in the comments, there are $5 \cdot 4 \cdot 3 = 60$ such distributions.

*Case 2*:  Exactly two balls are placed in one box, with the other ball placed in a separate box.

There are five ways to select the box which will receive two balls, $\binom{3}{2}$ ways to select which two balls will be placed in that box, and four ways to select which of the remaining boxes will receive the remaining ball.  There are
$$5 \cdot \binom{3}{2} \cdot 4 = 5 \cdot 3 \cdot 4 = 60$$
such distributions.

*Case 3*:  All five balls are placed in the same box.

There are five boxes in which all the balls could be placed, so there are $5$ such distributions.

*Total*:  Since the three cases are mutually exclusive and exhaustive, we can obtain the total number of distributions by adding the above cases, which yields $60 + 60 + 5 = 125$, as above.

Comment: Thanks for the answer , can't we go otherwise too like selecting balls first and then distributing them into the boxes

Comment: In case 1, once you have arranged the three balls, you can select which three of the five boxes will receive a ball, then arrange the balls in the selected boxes from left to right in the order you arranged the balls.   That yields $3!\binom{5}{3} = 60$ such distributions.  In case 2, once you select which two balls will be together, there are five ways to select the box which will receive the two balls and four ways to select the box which will receive the remaining ball, giving $\binom{3}{2} \cdot 5 \cdot 4 = 60$ such distributions.  In case 3, there are five ways to select the box.

Comment: why are we not arranging the balls in case 2 here like we did 3! in case 1 ?

Comment: The order of the balls within a box does not matter, just which boxes receive which balls.